# Parse text and link pairs from HTML into PHP array with same order

Tags: php, dom, domparser

Consider this HTML, littered with any whitespace or irrelevant tags like `div` and `span`:

```
<div>
<span><a href="#1">Title 1</a></span>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Outside 3
<a href="#4">Title 4</a>
</p>
</div>
```

How can I convert this into a PHP array of link and text pairs, in the same order as in the HTML.

```
{"#1", "Title 1"    },
{null, "Paragraph 2"},
{null, "Outside 3"  },
{"#4", "Title 4"    },
```

The problem is that DOM searches like `$html->find("a, p")` will capture 4 twice, once by itself and once inside 3.

I'm wondering if the solution is to traverse the document "linearly", as a human would read element by element from left to right, and if the node has text, you pick up the parent node's `href`, if any.

If this is viable, how do you easily go through the DOM like this? Does anyone have a solution, preferably with [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) or simple regexp, alternatively a built-in PHP framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at https://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/RecursiveDOMIterator Which will help you recursevly traverse dom structure.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<html>'.$htmlString.'</html>'); // wrap your initial html in <html></html> since it has to be well-formed
$dit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDOMIterator($dom));
$result = array();
foreach ($dit as $node) {
    unset($r);
    if(trim($node->nodeValue) == "" || $node->childNodes->length > 0){ // we look only non-empty last level nodes
        continue;
    }
    $parent = $node->parentNode;
    if($parent->nodeName == 'a'){
        $r[0] = $parent->getAttribute('href');
    }
    $r[1] = $node->nodeValue;
    $result[] = $r;
}
```

Comment: Of course... Jump from node to node on the same DOM level. I'll give this a try! I think my brain has developed a counter-productive aversion against DOM traversal in favour or one-line searches...

Comment: I couldn't quite get the example code to work. Anyway, I massaged the problem a bit and updated the original post with a somewhat more complicated example and a suggested approach.

Comment: So now elements are not on the same level. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a non-DOM approach by pondering my own neatly organised example! By splitting each tag into lines, I can easily extract the information I want. It's maybe not "correct", but works as intended!

```
$array = preg_split("#(?=<)#", $html, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach($array as $key => $item) {
    preg_match('/>\s*(\S.*)/', $item, $m);
    preg_match('/href="([^"]*)/', $item, $n);
}
```